# Creating a button or link dynamically with controller event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have a link in the component like so:

```
<a onclick="{!c.accountSelected}" data-accId="{!account.Id}">{!account.Name}</a>
```

I am trying to also do the same by building an anchor tag that also calls the same function but it looks like I don't have access to the accountSelected function.

Any advice on if this is possible?

Comment: What's happening? This should work - you might need to cancel the event however, as an anchor tag may try to redirect you on a click.

Comment: I am trying to build the link in JS in the helper class. It doesn't have reference to the c.accountSelected function or the component at all matter of fact.

Comment: I think I know what you want - I have created an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can dynamically create an `<a>` tag in create component - I need to verify this - however, you should be able to use the `component.getReference()` call to get access to your controller methods.

In your case you should probably use a `ui:outputUrl` standard component and your call would be something like:

```
$A.createComponent(
  "ui:outputUrl",
  {
      "data-accId": account.Id,
      "value": account.Name,
      "click": cmp.getReference("c.accountSelected")
  },
  ....rest of dynamic component creation code
```

See here from more details: [component reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

Comment: I should have included this in my question, but I need to add it to a leaflet popup content. http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup Can I still do this and add it to the marker's popup content?

Comment: Hi Brandon, did you get the answer to your question, If yes, please post your answer, Actually, I am facing same issue : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221781/referenceerror-c-is-not-defined-at-htmlanchorelement-onclick